# Deleting an image from two separate worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-365

I have an image on two worksheets within the same workbook.  One sheet is called "_SETUP" and the other sheet is "Layout1".  It all seems to be working as long as there really is an image...but if the image has already been deleted then it freaks out and throws an error. Errors are on the very last "if" 2 lines from the end:

> Application-defined or object-defined error '1004"

> object doesn't support this property or method

I am pretty sure I need to add logic to check if there is a Shape on the Worksheet before comparing the TopLeftCell.Address (since if it is empty, there is no such address or cell).  I have NO idea how to go about verifying that the Shape (in this case an image) exists prior to the error being thrown.

My code is here:

```
Private Sub killImages()
' first delete the primary image on the Layout1 sheet
Dim shBig As Shape
Set imgBigDeleteRange = Worksheets("Layout1").Range("A2")
For Each shBig In Worksheets("Layout1").Shapes
    If shBig.TopLeftCell.Address = imgBigDeleteRange.Address Then shBig.Delete
Next

' then delete the thumbnail on the _SETUP sheet
Dim shThumb As Shape
Set imgThumbDeleteRange = Worksheets("_SETUP").Range("L33")
For Each shThumb In Worksheets("_SETUP").Shapes
    If shThumb.TopLeftCell.Address = imgThumbDeleteRange.Address Then shThumb.Delete
Next
End Sub
```

I have tried changing to something like this but it does not seem to solve the issue 100% of the time:

```
If Worksheets("Layout1").Shapes.Count > 0 Then
For Each shBig In Worksheets("Layout1").Shapes
    If shBig.TopLeftCell.Address = imgBigDeleteRange.Address Then shBig.Delete
Next
End If
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.  If there is a way to simplify the deletion of 2 specific images from 2 specific cells, I am okay with that...this was just the closest I could get.

Comment: I can't see any problem occurring unless the sheet is protected.  `For Each shThumb In Worksheets("_SETUP").Shapes` will go through each shape on the sheet.  If the sheet doesn't have any then the `If` statement is skipped.